# Is there any way to reset Global variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a global variable with classname defined to it.

```
var className = "My Class is.";
```

And I will use that `className` variable to add more

```
var a = function() {
  className = className + "a" ;
  console.log(className);
}    
console.log(className);
a();
console.log(className);
```

But after calling the function `a()`, variable `className` is still holding the data. I believe this is how JS behaves, but is there any way to reset `className` variable every time when it comes out of a function.

Comment: Why not just use a local variable instead of updating the global variable?

Comment: @Barmar, I am defining a local variable named FunctionName with className:MethodName as format. If I can define a variable with className, then I can use that instead of placing complete className in every method, just trying avoid retyping and spelling mistakes mostly.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ - Then just *use* `className` without *modifying* it: `var methodName = className + "a";`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, looking like a good way of doing. Is it not possible to reset global variable after function call got over ?

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ - It's *possible*, just usually not best practice -- I've posted an answer with how.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59954983/is-there-any-way-to-reset-global-variable-in-javascript?noredirect=1#comment106029088_59954983):

> I am defining a local variable named FunctionName with className:MethodName as format. If I can define a variable with className, then I can use that instead of placing complete className in every method, just trying avoid retyping and spelling mistakes mostly.

...I think you want to just *use* `className` without *modifying* it:

```
var a = function() {
    var functionName = className + "a";
    // ...use functionName...
};
```

But if you really want to modify it for some reason, without using a local, then you can remember its old value and restore it:

```
var a = function() {
    var savedClassName = className + "a";
    try {
        className = className + "a";
        // ...use className...
    } finally {
        className = savedClassName;
    }
};
```

No matter how you exit the code in the `try` block, the `finally` block will be executed.

**But** there are very few use cases where that's the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a local variable with the same name, that is possible:

```js
var className = "My Class is."; // define global var

let a = function() {
  let className = window.className; // define local var and copy global var value to local var
  className = className + "a"; // modify local var
  console.log(className); // print local var
};

console.log(className); // print global var value
a(); // does not change global var value
console.log(className) // print unchanged global var value
```

But it would be much clearer to just have different names for your local and global variables:

```js
var className = "My Class is.";

let a = function() {
  let localClassName = className;
  localClassName = localClassName + "a";
  console.log(localClassName)
};

console.log(className);
a();
console.log(className)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. (Better) Don't add the letter in the first place

`var a = function() {
       console.log(className + "a");
     }`

or

```
var a = function() {
  let temp = className + "a" ;
  console.log(temp);
}
```

2. Store the original value

`

```
 var className = ...;
 var backup = className;

 var a = function() {
   className = className + "a" ;
   console.log(className);
 }    
 console.log(className);
 a();
 className = backup;
 console.log(className);
```

`